# Error 3075-Run Query after multi select listbox is utilized

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

have a search form in Access 2010 that filters FYs and Quarters based on certain criteria and opens them in a query. One of the criteria is an unbound multi-select list box, SelectTime (Where a person selects "FY15-Q1 and FY15 Q2, for example. The data are stored in a query, z_Basis_QSReport5_Proposal Details. I keep getting an error 3075. Can someone help me with the code?

```
Private Sub Command56_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb()
   Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("z_Basis_QSReport5_Proposal Details_For_Report")
For Each varItem In Me!SelectTime.ItemsSelected
  strCriteria = strCriteria & ",'" & Me!SelectTime.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
Next varItem
If Len(strCriteria) = 0 Then
  MsgBox "You did not select anything from the list" _
         , vbExclamation, "Nothing to find!"
  Exit Sub
   End If
   strCriteria = Right(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 1)
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM z_Basis_QSReport5_Proposal Details " & _
            "WHERE z_Basis_QSReport5_Proposal Details.CriteriaFY IN(" &           strCriteria & ");"
   qdf.SQL = strSQL
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "z_Basis_QSReport5_Proposal Details_For_Report"
   Set db = Nothing
   Set qdf = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating query, table, and field names; it is best practice to avoid spaces. However, there is a solution.

When you use SQL and you have a table name with spaces you need to encapsulate it in square brackets. like so:

```
"SELECT * FROM [z_Basis_QSReport5_Proposal Details] & _
        "WHERE [z_Basis_QSReport5_Proposal Details].CriteriaFY .....
```

> EDIT

Before, I mentioned that you should maybe put square brackets around the query name, but if you look at the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238028(office.12).aspx) you will see that spaces are acceptable in this instance.

If we go back to your query, `strcriteria` is a string and therefore you need to put single quotes around it:

```
 strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [z_Basis_QSReport5_Proposal Details] " & _
          "WHERE [z_Basis_QSReport5_Proposal Details].CriteriaFY IN('" & strCriteria & "');"
```

Also, you will need to close your query before you can run it. So `qdf.close` is required before the `docmd.openquery()`.

Comment: Thank you so much liam! but now there's a Run-Time Erro 7874 saying it can't find z_Basis_QSReport5_Proposal Details_For_Report

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @LiamH that you need to surround your query names with square brackets.

Also it looks like you're trying to change the SQL of a query on the fly - and then call the query before you've saved the changes

```
   qdf.SQL = strSQL
   **qdf.close**
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "z_Basis_QSReport5_Proposal Details_For_Report"
```

That being said I think you should be looking at parameter queries or just opening the SQL directly.